# Expanding Search Bar issue when search icon is on left on LTR website

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition

I am using [Expanding Search Bar](http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/ExpandingSearchBar/), but as per my requirement/design, the search icon should be on the left. So, I modified the code, by replacing `right` with `left`, `float: right` with `float: left` and swapped right padding with left padding for the search input.

Now, when I click on the search icon, the search input expands. But the search icon moves to the left until the transition is complete.

I guess because of the focus on the search input (`direction: ltr`), this problem is occurring. I don't know much about it. How to fix it?

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j7679/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add overflow: visible; to the search open state, it prevents the movement in Chrome:

```
.sb-search.sb-search-open, .no-js .sb-search {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: visible;
}
```

Here's the fiddle I was playing with: http://jsfiddle.net/MathiasaurusRex/j7679/1/

Comment: Thank you. This solves the problem. But what do you think about the issue? What is the reason the search icon moves to the left?

Comment: I suspect it has to do with the padding on .sb-search-input. When the search button is on the right it clears the padding.

When the search button is on the left the image doesn't clear the padding until the transition has completed, which would cause it to be pushed over until it does clear.